# Why can't I install this python module with pip?

Tags: python, pip

Why can't I install django-graphos? I have tried on Arch and Ubuntu and get this error:

```
pip install django-graphos
Downloading/unpacking django-graphos
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-graphos (from versions: 0.0.1a0, 0.0.2a0)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for django-graphos
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the package has no version specified.
run this command instead:

```
pip install django-graphos==0.0.2a
```

Hope that helps!